# how do i shorten this SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I run this command :

```
select * from LIST where JCODE = 8 and
KCODE = 01 and LCODE = 2011
```

and **if the above retruns no rows** then perform the below :

```
insert into LIST
select * from LIST@LNDB where JCODE = 8 and
KCODE = 01 and LCODE = 2011 and ban
in (select BAN from billing_account)

Update LIST set STS = null where JCODE = 8
AND KCODE = 01;

Update LIST set NO = '1' where JCODE = 8 AND
KCODE = 01;
```

moreover can i use some variable in the begininng which 
sets

```
JCODE= somevalue
KCODE= anothervalue
LCODE=someothervalue
```

so that i dont have to edit every line every time i run it.
I am using :

```
Oracle 9i Enterprise Edition release 9.2.8.0 - 64 bit Production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell for the `SELECT`, but you should be allowed to `UPDATE` several fields at once:

```
UPDATE LIST set STS = null , NO = '1' WHERE JCODE = 8 AND KCODE = 01;
```

Edit: I don't understand why you need the second `SELECT` (with `LIST@LNDB`), but in both queries I don't think you really need all the fields, so instead of using `SELECT *`, which is heavy for the system, use only and explicitly the primary key's field name (like `SELECT id FROM ...`).

And there is a way to do it in one request, probably something like:

```
UPDATE LIST set STS = null , NO = '1' WHERE JCODE = 8 AND KCODE = 01 AND 0<(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LIST WHERE JCODE = 8 AND KCODE = 01 AND LCODE = 2011);
```

This way, if there is no result found by `SELECT`, the `WHERE` clause in `UPDATE` will be false for every row, as 0<0 is false. There may also be a way to use `COUNT()` with a named field instead of `*`, I don't know Oracle enough for that.

Re-edit: indeed, if your second `SELECT` is actually an `INSERT`, you probably need that `*` :) But I don't think you can apply the same trick on the `INSERT` as the one on the `UPDATE`...

Re-re-edit: to write better what I put in the comment - taken from http://www.oradev.com/oracle_insert.jsp - your one and only request could be:

```
INSERT 
WHEN (0=(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM LIST WHERE JCODE=8 AND KCODE=01 AND LCODE=2011)) 
INTO LIST (field1, field2, field3, STS, field4, field5, NO, field6) 
SELECT field1, field2, field3, null, field4, field5, 1, field6 
    FROM LIST@LNDB 
    WHERE JCODE=8 AND KCODE=01 AND LCODE=2011 
    AND ban IN (SELECT BAN FROM billing_account)
```

Naturally you can add the GuZzie touch, use `DECLARE`, `BEGIN` and `END` to make the writing of parameters easier ;)

Comment: COUNT() can be used on wildcards and fieldnames in Oracle so your guess is correct :)

Comment: i have got LIST in two databases and i need to copy the coresponding values from the LNDB database if the LIST table in my curent database is empty. thats why I am using the select with LIST@LNDB.

Comment: Then is there a reason why you don't simply dump your whole LIST@LNDB into this DB's LIST ?

Comment: :-) i dont know about that moreover i need to copy only certain values like where jcode=something,kcode=something,lcode=something

Comment: According to http://www.oradev.com/oracle_insert.jsp Oracle can do conditional insertions. So you can do it in one request, something like:

Comment: INSERT WHEN (SELECT COUNT...)=0 INTO LIST SELECT field1, field2, null, field3, '1', field4 FROM LIST@LNDB...
I used generic names for the fields, to let you understand that you don't need the UPDATE request, just don't give STS and NO field to the INSERT, state them yourself statically inside the SELECT.

Comment: Oracle supports the SQL standard `MERGE INTO` syntax, which I think could also be used to do this. It is quite verbose, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two update queries.

```
Update LIST set STS = null, NO = '1' where JCODE = 8 AND KCODE = 01;
```

If you want to use variables you need to declare them and then simply call them in the query

```
DECLARE
    v_JCODE  NUMBER := 8;
    v_KCODE  NUMBER := 01;
    v_LCODE  NUMBER := 2011;

BEGIN
    Update LIST set STS = null, NO = '1' where JCODE = v_JCODE and KCODE = v_KCODE;
END;
/
```

EDIT: Due to the discussion and comments below I've made a PL/SQL procedure which should do what you are looking for. please note that you neet to replace the schemaname.procedure in the 1st row as this is the name of the procedure in the scheme you're currently working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schemaname.procedure is

-- Declare vars
v_JCODE  NUMBER := 8;
v_KCODE  NUMBER := 01;
v_LCODE  NUMBER := 2011;
v_checkvar NUMBER;

BEGIN

  select count(*)
  into v_checkvar
  from LIST 
  where JCODE = v_JCODE 
  and KCODE = v_KCODE
  and LCODE = v_LCODE;

  if v_checkvar = 0 then

    insert into LIST
    select * from LIST@LNDB 
    where JCODE = v_JCODE 
    and KCODE = v_KCODE 
    and LCODE = v_LCODE 
    and ban in (select BAN from billing_account);

    update LIST 
    set STS = null, NO = '1' 
    where JCODE = v_JCODE 
    and KCODE = v_KCODE;

  end if;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks @Guzzie but i need to do all this if the LIST table in my curent database has no rows.....see the first query how do i acive this

Comment: in PL/SQL you can program IF loops. Fill a variable with the result of the 1st query and then check if the variable is filled by an IF loop. If the variable is empty / not filled, execute the 2nd query and do the update statement.

Comment: I dont know much about SQL but I tried googling and tried `IF EXISTS(SELECT ..........)` but it didn't work